# Set Magento 2 session variable over AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, session, magento2

I am currently writing a Magento 2 module that requires me to log customer actions like product views. This action needs to be added for both logged in customers and guest customers. My solution is to use a custom variable (array) in the session for the customer of all product ID's.

To get around full page caching I have implemented a frontend ajax request to log the product views.

I have a controller that when visited will save the product ID in the session. This works as expected when I visit the URL directly, however, when its visited via an AJAX request the saving of the session variable does not work.

I have spent hours trying to debug this, I have been outputting the contents of the session variable and when accessed with AJAX I can see the contents, it's just never updated.

```

```
public function setGuestCustomerProductView($productId)
{
    $guestProductViews = $this->_sessionManager->getGuestProductViews();
    $guestProductViews[] = $productId;

    $this->_sessionManager->setGuestProductViews($guestProductViews);

    return $guestProductViews;
}
```

```

The AJAX request will always return the contents of the session variable (plus the product ID you are viewing) but never sets the variable. If I visit the URL directly in the same browser the contents are shown and the session variable is updated.

Further AJAX requests show the new session variable data from the direct URL request.

Have I misunderstood something in regards to sessions and AJAX requests? The domain is the same so there is no cross domain issues.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To confirm, you've injected the ```\Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session``` class into the $_sessionManager attribute for your class? Maybe call ```$this->_sessionManager->start();``` at the start of your method?

Comment: I am injecting `\Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager` into `$_sessionManager` and I tried adding `$this->_sessionManager->start();` but no luck either.

Comment: The strange thing is this works when viewing the page directly. It's only having issues via the AJAX call. I added another `$guestProductViews = $this->_sessionManager->getGuestProductViews();` immediately after setting the variable and its returning the new values. It just doesn't seem to retain them for the next request.

Comment: It sure sounds like a cross domain access issue you are having...  Is the full hostname the same on both the calling page and the ajax url?  Are you using GET or POST?

Comment: Yeah hostnames are the same for both. The ajax url is generated via the baseUrl helper in Magento. I was using GET for the request. If I take the URL which is being used in the AJAX request and view this directly in a new tab everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I am starting to think this is not a magento 2 issue and it's more of a general Session/AJAX issue.

I decided to test a theory and switch out the `SessionManager` and use PHP's `$_SESSION` global variable. This resulted in the same issue so it's not the handler that's the issue.

Further tests concluded the same session ID was being passed and used correctly. While using the `SessionManager` I called `isSessionExists()` directly before the set method. This method returned true which checks for not only a valid session ID but also confirms the headers haven't been sent.

I see no reason why this works directly in the browser but not over AJAX. I will continue to investigate unless someone posts and answer I can try out.

**SECOND UPDATE**

After several failed attempts to get this feature to work I have decided to drop the feature and try a different implementation. As it stands in my module I am not using cookies on the clients side to record the product views and then reading the cookie in PHP. This works perfectly.

I hope my investigations here helps someone in the future.